# handling reset in embedded systems

Tags: assembly, linker, embedded, interrupt, interrupt-handling

I was asked to work on bootloader program for embedded system. 
Main function of bootloader is to execute application.

Normally, without bootloader, memory organization for application was rather simple:

```
0x00 Reset
0x00000004 intrreupt vector
0x00000400 application.
```

Now, once bootloader apper, i have to shift memory region, so bootloader code will start from bottom:

```
0x00 Reset
0x00000004 bootloader interrupt vector
0x00000200 bootloader code
0x00001000 application code.
```

Now lets go to the question:
If bootloader do proper jump and application will be executed, what will happen once reset comes? Does application requires to have own reset handler, which, eg will be only jump to `0x00` address?

Im bit confused with this reset handling, what shall be the proper way to handle that.

thanks,
J.

Comment: What hardware/core are you using?

Comment: Explain how/why your cold and warm resets are different.  Or maybe that is your question?  (they are not/should not be different unless you are talking about an interrupt (timer/wdt/etc) rather than an actual reset.)

Comment: i have rh850. In application code i saw reset handler which i removed, since reset is handled by bootloader. But im not yet sure wheter it was necessary to remove this restet, thats why i asked.

Answer (score 0):

There will only be one reset vector. After all resets the bootloader will be restarted. If the application wants to reset and end up with execution control the bootloader must transfer control to the application.

A reset is not a jump to the reset vector but the core registers are reinitialized by hardware with the program counter pointing to reset address.

Comment: Your last paragraph is not true for most of the more modern CPUs.

Comment: @tofro Please give me more information, I would definitely like to know more.

Comment: Most modern CPUs don't reset the program counter to zero on reset. Most modern CPUs don't even expect executable code at address zero. Instead they either jump to a fixed (other) address on RESET or really jump to the address specified in the reset vector. x86 CPUs typically jump to an address towards the upper end of the address range, most ARMs, SPARCs, MIPS and Power CPUs use the address in the reset vector.

Comment: @tofro True, but it is still basically the same as the mechanism. Most processors boot from an fixed address vector initialized by the hardware. I used zero as it was what the question was about.

Comment: As you put it, "program counter pointing to address zero" implies "code starts at 0". You maybe wanted to say "program counter is initialized from address zero" (which is true for at least *some* CPUs like 68k)

Comment: @tofro: All PowerPC cores that I have used booted from a fixed vector at 0xfffffffe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157480/discussion-between-gerhard-and-tofro).

Answer (score 0):

Architectures may differ in the precise details, but even when your application and your bootloader have independent vector tables the effect of a reset includes resetting the vector table address to the default address, so there is only one reset vector.

Refer to the reference manual for your specific processor or architecture of the exact details.  It will include the reset state of all registers and peripherals.